# Flutter manage all the extra arguments

Tags: flutter

In my flutter code, I have created a widget called BeautifulTextField. I use a similar design for all my text fields in my code, so I just copied it into one class. However, a text field can have many parameters, such as `enableSuggestions`, `autocorrect`, `focusNode` etc. Only 1 out of 10 text fields might require these parameters. How can I manage them? This is my current code.

```
  String placeholder="";
  IconData icon;
  bool passField;
  double fontSize;
  EdgeInsets paddingText;
  BeautifulTextField(this.placeholder,this.icon,[
    this.passField=false,
    this.fontSize = -1,
    this.paddingText = const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,10,20,10)
  ]);
```

To elaborate further, I achieved this in react like this:

```
const Inputs = (props) => {

    return <input {...props} className="textfield"/>
}
```

Is there a similar feature in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Why don‘t you inherit a base class to a detailed class

```dart
class BeautifulText {
base properties
}

class MostBeautifulText extends BeautifulText {
extra properties
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use those fields as below when that fields are Optional,

```
String placeholder = "";
  IconData icon;
  bool passField;
  double fontSize;
  EdgeInsets paddingText;
  bool enableSuggession;
  bool autoCorrect;
  FocusNode focusNode;

  BeautifulTextField(this.placeholder, this.icon, this.passField, this.fontSize, this.paddingText,
      {this.enableSuggession, this.autoCorrect, this.focusNode});
```